# Wrong longitude and latitude values return from Google API autocomplete for addreses

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api, google-api-client

I'm using Google API Autocomplete Address Search and I'm trying to get Address name from latitude and longitude using this Javascript

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#stm-add-car-location').on('blur' , function() {
            var lat = jQuery("input[name='stm_lat']").val();
            var lng = jQuery("input[name='stm_lng']").val();

            jQuery.getJSON( {
                url  : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'',
                success : function( data, textStatus ) {
                    console.log( textStatus, data );
                    var address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
                }
            } );        

        });
      });
```

and I'm getting wrong lat and lng values every time I choose address from autocomplete. If I choose address then click again on input, and leave input I got right results, but when I choose option from autosuggestion I got wrong lat and lng values.

How can I resolve this issue? Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Show your option selection code

Comment: Code fragment shows that you use reverse geocoding lookup for coordinates, but it's not clear there is your issue. Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue?